# S3 PutObject Access Denied when deploying to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to create an IAM user whose sole job is to deploy to AWS S3 Static Website.

I have this policy given to my DeployUser:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.<my-site-name>.com"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.<my-site-name>.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.<my-site-name>.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the issue I get when I deploy (I am using Github Actions for this):

```
upload failed: public/404.html to s3://www.<my-site-name>.com/404.html An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

In Github, I passed the access key and secret of the user to my Action. I am pretty sure it is using that user to do the transaction. When I give S3FullAccess, my user is able to do it just fine. But I want to create a user with the AWS actions it only needs.

Where can I see better logs of this IAM user's actions?

Comment: Your bucket policy only allows `GetObject`, so cant Put anything to it.

Comment: @Marcin would I make a second statement with the principal as my IAM user and have that be `S3:PutObject`?

Comment: Yes. But for console access, more permissions are needed. For CLI or API, just single `S3:PutObject` should be enough.

Comment: Ah-ha! It worked, add it as an answer and I'll include. This is the first time I've ever had a restricted user for deploys not using S3FullAccess policy! Thank you! :D

Comment: @Marcin quick question: do I even need the IAM policy then at this point? Could I just have this all set up in the Bucket policy???

Comment: Bucket should be enough. But its worth testing out and see which way is better (e.g. easier to manage or more readable).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the solution was to add `PutObject` in the backed policy for the `DeployUser`.

Comment: so I removed my permissions from the IAM user and it does not work. Only works if user has S3FullAccess...again. I think the bucket policy is right but need to look IAM user permissions?